# Tomcat not loading Dispatcher Servlet (ClassNotFoundException)

Tags: spring, tomcat, spring-mvc

I have tried to search and make changes as per answers for above question, but not working. I am not using  any build tool.

All the jar files jstl1.2, common loggings 1.1.3 , and Spring 3.2.3 jars are in WebContent/WEB-INF/lib

index.jsp is welcome file is shown properly in Eclipse browser, but when I click on hyperlink for controller, give 404 Requested resource not available. From the log seems tomcat is not loading dispatcher servlet

I tried restarting/clean and publish tomcat,

using tomcat 7, jre7, eclipse kepller 4.0, with java ee 2.0

Appreciate your help

Tomcat logs:

```
   ul 02, 2013 1:16:52 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
    I**NFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
    Jul 02, 2013 1:16:52 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
    INFO: Marking servlet spring as unavailable
    Jul 02, 2013 1:16:52 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
    SEVERE: Servlet /SpringMVC threw load() exception
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:             org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet**
            
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1713)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1558)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:527)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:509)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1144)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1088)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5407)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Jul 02, 2013 1:16:53 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jul 02, 2013 1:16:53 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jul 02, 2013 1:16:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 11462 ms
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>SpringMVC</display-name>

     <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
 
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

spring-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"

    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan
        base-package="com.maverick.springmvc.controller" />

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

HelloWorldController.java

```
package com.maverick.springmvc.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;


@Controller
public class HelloWorldController {


    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    public ModelAndView helloWorld() {

        System.out.println("test");
        String message = "Hello World, Spring 3.0!";
        return new ModelAndView("hello", "message", message);
    }
}
```

Comment: try to search for the `DispatcherServlet` in build path, using ctrl+shift+T (in eclipse) and see if one if the resulting jars is contained in your project lib

Comment: @LaabidiRaissi: Hi, as you mentioned it was not showing in project lib, I did attach source but didnt work.
How do we make sure that all jars are in project lib, i copied all jars in WebInf/lib folder.

Isnt this enough or we need to something else? Thanks for pointing this out

Comment: Do we need source file? i think only .class file should be enough?

Comment: right click on your jars --> Build path --> Add to build path (in eclipse of course)

Comment: of course we need only the binary jars, but since the class was not found on your classpath, then, it's not correctly added to it

Answer (score 2):

Based on the stack trace you are missing spring-webmvc.jar which contains DispatcherServlet class. Try check your classpath again (WEB-INF/lib) to make sure that jar is there. Typically on a Spring MVC application you'll need these jars:

[image]

I also recommend you use dependency management tool (eg: Maven / ivy) otherwise it's too hard to manage the jars yourselves

Comment: I do have above mentioned jar in the (WEB-INF/lib). But its not working. I have added my eclipse project explorer view. Let me know if you find any issues with that

Comment: its not allowing to add images but I am sure that jar is present in directory you have said

Comment: I was missing commons-logging-1.1.1.jar. I 've wasted almost 3 hours.............finally it worked. Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Just add all needed jar files to WEB-INF/lib folder, then it works for me.
in this case only that DispatcherServlet class found